# No IsManipulationEnabled property in UWP

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

I have a UWP application where I am trying to enable manipulation events on the UI elements. I subscribed to the ManipulationStarted event but realized that it was not firing. Then, based on some suggestions, I tried setting IsManipulationEnabled property on the Grid but started getting compilation error saying that IsManipulationEnabled property could not be found. Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsManipulationEnabled` is a WPF property. In order to get manipulation events in UWP, you'll have to set the `ManipulationMode` property.

From the Remarks section on the [`ManipulationMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode) page:

> You must set the ManipulationMode to a value other than System or None
>   if you want to handle manipulation events such as ManipulationStarted
>   from UI elements in your app code.

E.g.

```
ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.Scale
    | ManipulationModes.TranslateX
    | ManipulationModes.TranslateY
    | ManipulationModes.TranslateInertia;
```

Comment: Thanks. Setting ManipulationMode fixed the problem.